# What kind of animal can do this?

Tags: zoology

[image]

When I was moving to another house, I found this plastic bag on the top of the cabinet of my old house. It looks like someone cut it all with a scissor, but no one have access to my bedroom, and it was not me.

I don't thing it could be rats. That bedroom was very tiny and closed, there's no way for a rat to enter.

The house is very near [a university with a little "forest"](https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Universidade+de+S%C3%A3o+Paulo/@-23.5671719,-46.7272143,2057m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x4f4f4d2c7e06e56), there are many types of mosquito and little flying animals, but I can't imagine which could do this.

I'm just curious. (and not sure if "zoology" is the correct tag here, but I had to choose one)

Comment: How old is this bag? How is been exposed to light for a long time?

Comment: @Chris about 2 years old. Exposed to lamplight from 19h to 22hs (when I was home), and not directly exposed to sunlight. The cabinet was on the same wall as the window, and it's top (where this bag was) was higher than the window. But a little sunlight was entering the room during the day, through the glass window. Not directly, as the windows was close to another wall outside.

Comment: Then I would suspect this is due to decay of the material of the bag. I have seen similar bags which sat on shelves for years and literally fell into pieces when touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your plastic bag tears are most likely due to light damage as @Chris mentioned above, there is a type of ant that chews its way through plastic, rubber and other manufactured polymers: *Monomorium pharaonis*, the [Pharaoh ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharaoh_ant).

[image]

It is [capable of destroying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharaoh_ant#Invasiveness_and_extermination) many manufactured materials and is a great example of [budding](http://www.pestproducts.com/pharaohants.htm), a method by which new ant colonies form. They are very invasive and [difficult to control](http://combattermitespecialist.com/ants/).